# .net c# Socket.SendFile method, how to use pre- and postBuffer param and receive this information

Tags: c#, .net, file, sockets, tcp

I currently have an application that uses the .NET C# .SendFile() method.

```
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Connect(endPoint);
client.SendFile(filePath);
```

And I have a very simple receive file solution that goes something like this. Takes the the bits read and append it to a file basically:

```
 ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        StateObject tempState = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = tempState.workSocket;
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        BinaryWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivePath, FileMode.Append));
            writer.Write(tempState.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
            Thread.Sleep(30);
        }
        finally
        {

            if (writer != null)
            {
                writer.Close();
            }

            // this method starts a new  AsyncCallback(ReadCallback)
            // and this method is ReadCallback so it works as a recursive method
            handler.BeginReceive(tempState.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), tempState);
        }
```

Now I want to add additonal info like: filename, file size, md5 hash etc to the transfer.

So I wonder how if I send this for example:

```
byte[] preBuffer = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
byte[] postBuffer ={ 5, 6, 7, 8 };
.SendFile(filePath, preBuffer, postBuffer, TransmitFileOptions.None)
```

How can I receive this information and separate it from the binary file that I write? How should I change my receive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to append data to the file received on the other end, don't use `postBuffer`.  i.e. if you want to send meta information about the file, only use preBuffer.  In this case I recommend serializing the data to an in memory buffer then sending that buffer as the preBuffer and deserializing it on the other end.  For example:

```
byte[] preBuffer;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        writer.Write(filePath);
        writer.Write(fileLength);
        writer.Write(md5Hash);
    }
    preBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
mySocket.SendFile(filePath, preBuffer, null,
    TransmitFileOptions.UseDefaultWorkerThread);
```

Then, when you want to read the meta information and file, read the pre-data first, and the remaining will be the file.  For example:

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject tempState = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = tempState.workSocket;
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(tempState.buffer))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream))
        {
            var filename = reader.ReadString();
            var length = reader.ReadInt32();
            var md5Hash = reader.ReadString();
            var fileData = new byte[memoryStream.Length - memoryStream.Position];
            reader.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            try
            {
                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(
                    File.Open(receivePath, FileMode.Append)))
                {
                    writer.Write(tempState.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
            finally
            {
                // this method starts a new  AsyncCallback(ReadCallback)
                // and this method is ReadCallback so it works as a recursive method
                handler.BeginReceive(tempState.buffer,
                    0,
                    StateObject.BufferSize,
                    0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback),
                    tempState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```